# ProgrammingError at /user_booking not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Tags: mysql, django

The idea is to display user's booking information like booking_name, package etc. I am fetching the data from database in my views.py like this.

```
def user_booking(request):
    id = request.session['u_id']
    booking_data = Booking.objects.raw('select * from booking WHERE id = %s',id)
    return render(request,'user_booking.html',{'view_data':booking_data})
```

Now in user_booking.html is displaying data. I have used a proper template to display data in tabular format. Problem is when some data is returned from data base it works perfect. When there is a query for which no data can be found the page breaks and shows
`"ProgrammingError at /user_booking not all arguments converted during bytes formatting"`

Instead of all the formatting I resorted to basic code which looks like this

```
 <html>
 {%  for b in view_data %}
{{b.b_name}}
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

It gives me the name `"ajay"` as output and does not break the page, also note that record for ajay's ID is present in my database. Now if ID is changed and then I refresh the lage again it gives me error.

What I am trying to do is if there is any data coming from the database then display it otherwise just display "no data here" msg.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: I suggest reading [Django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/) docs first. Do you have some complex SQL query instead of plain `SELECT`? If not, then `Booking.objects.filter(id=id)` would fit much better. The problem with your code is that `.raw(code, params)` expects iterable as params, not `int`. `.raw('SELECT ...', (id,))` should work too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help. Saved my neck. I wasted 4 hours on this